# Where can I find a feed of actual spam emails?

Tags: email, spam

I am looking for a feed of e-mail spam messages. I searched for one but found nothing that I can use. Does anyone know a site or service that offers a feed of actual spam messgaes that are currently used by spammers?

Comment: Why would you want this? To test a filter, or something similar?

Comment: Yes. I want to extract some information out of the feed.

Comment: It's not email, but the network here is protected from spam partially by a bot called SmokeDetector. We've accumulated 27,000 spam posts from that in a database. I'd have to check with the administrator, but I imagine we'd be happy to share that with you if you'd like.

Comment: @ArtOfCode That migth be really helpfull. I am interested in banking fraud related spam.

Comment: @alive-and-well Let me check whether we can do that, and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @alive-and-well For now, here's [a 100-post JSON sample](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search.json?body=financial). You can use the `?page=` query string to get the next page, but please don't use it as an API - the server isn't built to handle that kind of load. We're working on a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

These are hard to get.  Generally, you need to create and curate your own [spamtrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamtrap) (hard!) or else get data from some existing spam trap.  There are resources for this.  See the following highly related questions:

- [[image: SO] Brainstorm: How to quickly create a honeypot for mass spam?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/892193/519360)
- [[image: SO] Publicly Available Spam Filter Training Set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4743996/519360)
- [[image: secSE] Spear phishing data set](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/94874/42391)
- [[image: secSE] Databases with spam, phishing email examples](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/117452/42391) (an extended version of this answer)