# Phishing email repository for analysis

Tags: phishing

Is there a repository of known phishing emails somewhere that is available for analysis purposes? I want to test some mitigation theories and need a good collection of data to test against.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the type, "where can I find X?" are off-topic as the answers may change from day to day.

Comment: Your personal spam folder is likely to have far more samples than you could want. If you want to test mitigation theories, then you will have to break down what elements of a phish that you would want to mitigate. Once you define that, finding samples is much easier.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Databases with spam, phishing email examples](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/117370/databases-with-spam-phishing-email-examples) and [Spear phishing data set](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94874/spear-phishing-data-set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least a quite good collection of spam mails as such available at http://artinvoice.hu/spams/. I would consider phishing mails as a a subcategory of spam and expect you to also find phishing mails in that body.